Null values show as empty string in Bulk API 2.0 query results
I'm using the Bulk API 2.0 to query for records and receive an empty string instead of null values (I expected '#N/A' similar to when inserting records).
I sent the following to POST /services/data/v61.0/jobs/query:
{
  "operation": "query",
  "query": "SELECT Name,Birthdate FROM Contact"
}

And received a successful job ID.
When querying for its results at /services/data/v61.0/jobs/query/750...IAY/results I received:
"Name","Birthdate"
"Contact Name",""

Even though that contact has no value stored for Birthdate.
For reference, when running this using the SF CLI:
sf data query -o user@domain.com --query "SELECT Name,Birthdate FROM Contact" --json
I received:
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "records": [
      {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "Contact",
          "url": "/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/Contact/003...IAJ"
        },
        "Name": "Contact Name",
        "Birthdate": null
      }
    ],
    "totalSize": 1,
    "done": true
  },
  "warnings": []
}

Is that expected? Is there no way to distinguish between empty strings and null values in the bulk query response?

empty string and null are essentially the same right? both indicates the absence of value

Is there no way to distinguish between empty strings and null values in the bulk query response - have you tried updating a field with a zero-length string? See what happens.

@identigral ok, trying to update the Birthdate field with a string value triggers an error with SF not able to parse the date value, so I'm assuming (?) empty string for a field means it is null?

Also, took it 1 step further and tried updating Department (which is a string field), updating to a valid string works as expected, and when updating it to an empty string ("") - querying for it returns null. Can you or anyone else confirm Salesforce simply treats empty strings for text fields as null? (and therefore returns an empty string to represent null for any other data type?)

treats is a loaded term. For String fields that are null-valued in the "database", the response of reads (queries) depends on the API. Bulk API doesn't send nulls as you've discovered, other APIs do. On updates - for the common use cases of DML via Apex, nulls are written.

@prem22, from a platform point-of-view, I think it's important to distinguish between null and an empty value, and consistency across different APIs is definitely important. The reason I brought up the question was because some APIs responded with null and SF has a notion of null for CSV. I agree that if Salesforce uses empty strings to represent null - I can build for that, but I was looking for some reference or clarification before I make this assumption.

Gotcha @identigral so, given my experiment of updating a string field to an empty string, and then querying for it - yields a null, does it generally sound safe to build an integration that treats empty strings as nulls when querying for data, knowing that even string fields updated with an empty string will be eventually read as null?

@ZvikaT It depends on the integration? Unit/integration tests are a good way to ensure safety.
